# Unidirectional relation query

Tags: java, jpa, orm, spring-data, jpql

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOKS")
public class Book {

@Id
private Long id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID")
private List<Page> pages = new ArrayList<>(); 
...
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PAGES")
public class Page {

@Id
private Long id;

@Column(name = "COLOR", nullable = false)
private String color;

...
...
}
```

Given a specific page, I would like to find out the book it belongs to (according to the page's color for example).

After I've generated the tables in the database, using liquibase, I can execute the following query:

```
select * from Books where id in (select book_id from Pages where color = ?)
```

I'm using Spring Data (JpaRepository), but when I tried to compose the JPQL query I found out I can't... since the relation is Unidirectional (which I don't want to change).

My question is - how can I compose this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct b from Book b
join b.pages p 
where p.color = :color
```

Comment: Thanks! that indeed solved the issue - I've accepted this answer and not the other one since it was published first...